# QueryString in domnio xpages or not, not normalized

Tags: query-string, xpages, lotus-domino

I'm trying to adapt an application with domino xpages. The html request send by client are like `http://www.someserver.org/someapplication.nsf/someresource.png?v=2.3.4` or `http://www.someserver.org/someapplication.nsf/somerresource.swf?x=27421`, that are not standard domino url query string.

Anybody know, how I have to implement this response in the server side?

Comment: What about an XAgent wich handles the url parameter and returns the requested resource back to the client?

Comment: IMHO resources under WebContent/WEB-INF folder are accessible that way. Do you expect to store them in other place? Did you try redirect rules in Domino Directory?

Comment: Hello Michael:  How do you think that this can occur?, if the client asks a resource?.  Frantisek:  How can I manage the rest of QueryString?

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the query string you need to have an XPage (with content or without content as XAgent), so you can get access to the querystring. For your example you could use a Internet site rule to actually redirect the content to:

```
   http://www.someserver.org/someapplication.nsf/resourcepage.xsp?file=somerresource.swf&x=27421
```

The rest should be easy

Comment: Hello Stephan,  Thanks for your help. I always follow your work, thanks for share your knowledge with the community.  I had thought about XAgent (Your post about them are brilliant) but in this case, I can´t modify the url request using substitution rules on the server since I can´t modify the client request also. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not? If your request is some.nsf/some gif?some parameters it is easy to map that to some.nsf/thexpage.xsp?some. gift...

Comment: You are all right, but can you help me? I'm testing in local mode and I don't know how to reach substitution rules...  On the server I'll see how I cheat to domain admin.

Comment: Anyway, could I try to do something similar to what used on page 375 of the book "XPages Extension Library. A Stept-by-step Guide to the Next Generation of Xpages Components"? Would using something like DefaultServletFactory?

Comment: Local preview has no substitution rules. Unless you go through the trouble of setting up a local HTTP reverse proxy (Apache ngix etc) you are out of luck. Or just install a local server